# How to filter by distinct AND Max in Excel

Tags: excel, filter

hmmm. Thought this was like a normal forum.   Ok it's not copying my highlight.    I have complex and changing data sets  this is a simple version.  I want to some how filter the following:

```
state   number  seq OP
KY  831222  1   Apple
KY  831222  2   Apple
KY  831222  3   Apple
KY  845678  2   orange
KY  845678  3   orange
KY  845678  4   orange
KY  845678  2   Banana
KY  845678  3   Banana
KY  845678  4   Banana
PA  4567890 4   Apple
PA  4567890 5   Apple
```

So that I only see the following:

```
KY  831222  3   Apple
KY  845678  4   orange
KY  845678  4   Banana
PA  4567890 5   Apple
```

That is I want to filter/group by the MAX seq for EACH set.   I THiNK if this was seq I'd do it something like this: 
Select Distinct State,number,max(seq), OP  From (table created from range)   group by KY,number,OP

BUT how do I do it in EXCEL?  I know there is a seq wizard thing but I can never get it to work right.  Inbedding a sql query in a macro may be doable.
I am a little past beginner with macros. I generally record then figure stuff out later.  So I may not understand terms.

OK This looks fine up here in the copy/paste write area but the "draft area" at the bottom looks like it's squishing things together.  I don't have time to figure out how to format this so it looks like the table I'm seeing.  I just hope this displays correctly.
Thanks for any help
- Sharon

Tried various types of filtering.  Tried a pivot table - it just makes a mess - doesn't even display the data neatly.  Tried the sql wizard but it's clunky.

Answer (score 0):

Few steps:

- Select your range > Data Tab > Sort
- Add 4 levels of sorting: `State` - `Number` - `OP` - `Seq`
- Only edit to make: Sort `Seq` from Large to Small
- Apply
- Keep range selected > Data Tab > Remove Duplicates
- All boxes need to be checked but `Seq`
- Apply

[image]

We need to first sort the range on `Seq` column largest to smallest since remove duplicates will work bottum-top.